# Unable to save a model by assigning values to each attributes in Yii

Tags: yii

```
 $model=new TestModel;
 $data = $_GET['data'];                     //get json object from ajax request 
 $record = json_decode($data);              //convert json to objects
 $model->url = $record['info']['bg'];       //assign url 
 $model->user_id = 123;                     //assign user id 
 $model->save();
```

*The error says:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in.*

Can someone explain to me why this error occurs? I am new to yii

Comment: [`json_decode`](http://us.php.net/json_decode) produces *objects*, not *arrays* by default. Use `json_decode($data, true)` to get an array.

Comment: @DCoder: please answer so that I can mark that your answer as answered :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$record = json_decode($data, true); 


mixed json_decode ( string $json [, bool $assoc = false [, int $depth = 512 [, int $options = 0 ]]] )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax:

```
$model->url = $record->info->bg;
```